# Laravel, is there a way to include codes from resource/view path into controller?

Tags: php, laravel

My goal is to include codes from another sources which is located in resources/views. I have tried using `resource_path('views/myfiles.php')` but it does nothing.

**Controller**

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function test(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->input('name') == "chair")
        {
            $theFilesLocation = "resources.views" . $request->input('name');
            @include($theFilesLocation) //something like this
        }

    }
}
```

**myfiles.php**

```
<?php
    dump("if this shows up, then the code works")
?>
```

Comment: What would be the use of that? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Please check this for [template inheritance](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#template-inheritance)

Comment: @kerbholz updated my question...wanted to use the content of the files base on the user request

Comment: `return view($theFilesLocation)` instead of `@include($theFilesLocation)` ?

Comment: @kerbholz but if I do that, the code below it will never executed

Comment: At least for me this needs a little more explanation of what you are trying to do here. "Best" way would be to assign `$request->input('name')` to your view and handle view/partial display there. There should be nothing in your view/`.blade.php` file that you need in your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php). This allows the easy sharing of code and functionality without having to inherit from a specific base class causing an inheritance hell.

```
namespace MyCode\Traits;

trait SharedCodeForThing {
   public function blaTheBla() {
       dump("if this shows up, then the code works");
   }
}
```

and then in your controller

```
use  MyCode\Traits\SharedCodeForThing ;
class MyController extends Controller
{
    use SharedCodeForThing;
}
```

Now if you wish to just render the contents of the view which it seems you're after:

```
public function test(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->input('name') == "chair")
        {
            $view = view('resources.views' . $request->input('name'));
            return $view->render();//or echo $view->render(); whatever you like
        }
    }
```

Comment: so i should put my myfiles.php in resources/views?

Comment: @learnprogramming if you wish to extend functionality of your class you should use traits. If you wish to render the specific views, you should just render them, not include them. I modified my answer.

Comment: can i put the traits under resources/views...if can, how do i locate it? like this? `namespace Resources\Views\MyCode\Traits`?

Comment: @learnprogramming You put traits as where you would put your controller classes, perhaps in a subdirectory called traits so instead of LearnProgramming\Controllers you'd put it in LearnProgramming\Traits. Have you seen my edit to my answer?

Comment: yes i tried the code that u edit...but it will not execute the code after return tho

Comment: the return value is the outputted code generated by the view. You have to echo it somewhere. I have no idea where you're calling test() from.

Answer (score 2):

Try bellow code but I think it is not a good way.

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
     require_one(resource_path('views/myfile');
}
```

Or with Laravel File facade

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
     \File::requireOnce(resource_path('views/myfile');
}
```

You should create a class and put your code there then call it from the controller is a better solution.

Comment: `You should create a class and put your code there then call it from the controller is a better solution.` can you provide an example on how to do this?